# How to explode nested json array in data frame

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

This is my input data frame structure

```
root
|--Name (String)
|--Version (int)
|--Details (array)
```

Something like this :

```
"Name":"json",
"Version":1,
"Details":[
"{
    \"Id\":\"123\",
    \"TaxDetails\":[\"TaxDetail1\":\"val1\", \"TaxDetail2\":\"val2\"]
}",
"{
    \"Id\":\"234\",
    \"TaxDetails\":[\"TaxDetail3\":\"val3\", \"TaxDetail4\":\"val4\"]
}"
]
```

I want to explode this at level of TaxDetails something like this :

```
"Name":"json",
"Version":1,
"TaxDetail":{\"TaxDetail1\":\"val1\"}   

"Name":"json",
"Version":1,
"TaxDetail":{\"TaxDetail2\":\"val2\"}   

"Name":"json",
"Version":1,
"TaxDetail":{\"TaxDetail3\":\"val3\"}   

"Name":"json",
"Version":1,
"TaxDetail":{\"TaxDetail4\":\"va4\"}
```

I have exploded the Details with explode function like this

```
val explodedDetailDf = inputDf.withColumn("Detail", explode($"Details"))
```

Now the data type of column 'Detail' is string and when I am trying to do this:

```
val explodedTaxDetail = explodedDetailDf.withColumn("TaxDetail", explode($"Detail.TaxDetails"))
```

Above operation is failing with error "AnalysisException due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not String"

How can I explode a nested json array based on it's name?

Comment: You have to use the `from_json()` function from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` to turn the JSON string column into a structure column first.

Comment: your json is corrupted

Comment: hi can you check my answer suites you well ? I have not created manual schema with the existing corrupted json I formatted and used

Comment: also I used explode function twice with out using from_json which is common way of doing  just have look at it. if needed we can further discuss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`explode` will take values of type map or array. but not string

From your sample json `Detail.TaxDetails` is of type string not array.

To extract `Detail.TaxDetails` string type values you have to use

`def from_json(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType): org.apache.spark.sql.Column`

`Note`

Your json is corrupted, I have modified your json like below.

```
scala> val json = """{
     |   "Name": "json",
     |   "Version": 1,
     |   "Details": [
     |     "{\"Id\":\"123\",\"TaxDetails\":[{\"TaxDetail1\":\"val1\", \"TaxDetail2\":\"val2\"}]}",
     |     "{\"Id\":\"234\",\"TaxDetails\":[{\"TaxDetail3\":\"val3\", \"TaxDetail4\":\"val4\"}]}"
     |   ]
     | }"""

json: String =
{
  "Name": "json",
  "Version": 1,
  "Details": [
    "{\"Id\":\"123\",\"TaxDetails\":[{\"TaxDetail1\":\"val1\", \"TaxDetail2\":\"val2\"}]}",
    "{\"Id\":\"234\",\"TaxDetails\":[{\"TaxDetail3\":\"val3\", \"TaxDetail4\":\"val4\"}]}"
  ]
}
```

Please check the below code how to extract value for `Detail.TaxDetails`

```
scala> val df = spark.read.json(Seq(json).toDS)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Details: array<string>, Name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- Details: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Version: long (nullable = true)

scala> df.withColumn("details",explode($"details").as("details")).show(false) // inside details array has string values.
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----+-------+
|details                                                               |Name|Version|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----+-------+
|{"Id":"123","TaxDetails":[{"TaxDetail1":"val1", "TaxDetail2":"val2"}]}|json|1      |
|{"Id":"234","TaxDetails":[{"TaxDetail3":"val3", "TaxDetail4":"val4"}]}|json|1      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----+-------+

scala> val json = spark.read.json(Seq("""[{"Id": "123","TaxDetails": [{"TaxDetail1": "val1","TaxDetail2": "val2"}]},{"Id": "234","TaxDetails": [{"TaxDetail3": "val3","TaxDetail4": "val4"}]}]""").toDS).schema.json
json: String = {"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"Id","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"TaxDetails","type":{"type":"array","elementType":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"TaxDetail1","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"TaxDetail2","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"TaxDetail3","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"TaxDetail4","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"containsNull":true},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}

scala> val schema = DataType.fromJson(json).asInstanceOf[StructType] // Creating schema for inner string
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(Id,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetails,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(TaxDetail1,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetail2,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetail3,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetail4,StringType,true)),true),true))

scala> spark.time(df.withColumn("details",explode($"details")).withColumn("details",from_json($"details",schema)).withColumn("id",$"details.id").withColumn("taxdetails",explode($"details.taxdetails")).select($"name",$"version",$"id",$"taxdetails.*").show(false))
+----+-------+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|name|version|id |TaxDetail1|TaxDetail2|TaxDetail3|TaxDetail4|
+----+-------+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|json|1      |123|val1      |val2      |null      |null      |
|json|1      |234|null      |null      |val3      |val4      |
+----+-------+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+


scala>
```

`Updated`

Above I have taken json manually & created schema. Please check the below code to get schema from the available data.

```
scala> spark.read.json(df.withColumn("details",explode($"details").as("details")).select("details").map(_.getAs[String](0))).printSchema
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TaxDetails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- TaxDetail1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TaxDetail2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TaxDetail3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TaxDetail4: string (nullable = true)


scala> spark.read.json(df.withColumn("details",explode($"details").as("details")).select("details").map(_.getAs[String](0))).schema
res12: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(Id,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetails,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(TaxDetail1,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetail2,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetail3,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetail4,StringType,true)),true),true))

scala> val schema = spark.read.json(df.withColumn("details",explode($"details").as("details")).select("details").map(_.getAs[String](0))).schema
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(Id,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetails,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(TaxDetail1,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetail2,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetail3,StringType,true), StructField(TaxDetail4,StringType,true)),true),true))

scala> spark.time(df.withColumn("details",explode($"details")).withColumn("details",from_json($"details",schema)).withColumn("id",$"details.id").withColumn("taxdetails",explode($"details.taxdetails")).select($"name",$"version",$"id",$"taxdetails.*").show(false))
+----+-------+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|name|version|id |TaxDetail1|TaxDetail2|TaxDetail3|TaxDetail4|
+----+-------+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|json|1      |123|val1      |val2      |null      |null      |
|json|1      |234|null      |null      |val3      |val4      |
+----+-------+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+

Time taken: 212 ms

scala>
```

Comment: Sorry for the corrupted json file. I had created this data from my actual data and posted it without checking. Thnx @Srinivas for answer. You have created json manually while creation of schema. Can you please explain how to get the string from Df directly?

Comment: I have taken manually those strings & created dataframe to get schema, Now i have updated code to get schema from the available DF.

Comment: @Srinivas with out fromjson function I did it, you can have a look at it. some one downvoted with out mentioning the reason for it.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram, Sure I will check that. Details is an array of string so i have to use from_json function to convert string to object. In your json has Details is an array of object so no need to use from_json there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the earlier json you gave was corrupted, I formatted json in this way you can work with your `explode` 2 times and flatten the dataframe.

Implemented like below...

```
 package examples

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object JsonTest extends App {
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)

  private[this] implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val jsonString =
    """
      |{
      |  "Name": "json",
      |  "Version": "1",
      |  "Details": [
      |    {
      |      "Id": "123",
      |      "TaxDetails": [
      |        {
      |          "TaxDetail1": "val1",
      |          "TaxDetail2": "val2"
      |        }
      |      ]
      |    },
      |    {
      |    "Id":"234",
      |    "TaxDetails":[
      |    {
      |    "TaxDetail3":"val3"
      |    , "TaxDetail4":"val4"
      |    }
      |    ]
      |}
      |  ]
      |}
    """.stripMargin
  val df3 = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString).toDS)
  df3.printSchema()
  df3.show(false)
  val explodedDetailDf = df3.withColumn("Detail", explode($"Details"))
  // explodedDetailDf.show(false)
  val explodedTaxDetail = explodedDetailDf.withColumn("TaxDetail", explode($"Detail.TaxDetails"))
  explodedTaxDetail.show(false)

  val finaldf = explodedTaxDetail.select($"Name", $"Version"
    , to_json(struct
    (col("TaxDetail.TaxDetail1").as("TaxDetail1"))
    ).as("TaxDetails"))
    .union(
      explodedTaxDetail.select($"Name", $"Version"
        , to_json(struct
        (col("TaxDetail.TaxDetail2").as("TaxDetail2"))
        ).as("TaxDetails"))
    )
    .union(
      explodedTaxDetail.select($"Name", $"Version"
        , to_json(struct
        (col("TaxDetail.TaxDetail3").as("TaxDetail3"))
        ).as("TaxDetails"))
    )
    .union(
      explodedTaxDetail.select($"Name", $"Version"
        , to_json(struct
        (col("TaxDetail.TaxDetail4").as("TaxDetail4"))
        ).as("TaxDetails"))
    ).filter(!($"TaxDetails" === "{}"))

  finaldf.show(false)
  finaldf.toJSON.show(false)
}
```

Result :

```
root
 |-- Details: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TaxDetails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- TaxDetail1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- TaxDetail2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- TaxDetail3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- TaxDetail4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Version: string (nullable = true)

+---------------------------------------------------+----+-------+
|Details                                            |Name|Version|
+---------------------------------------------------+----+-------+
|[[123, [[val1, val2,,]]], [234, [[,, val3, val4]]]]|json|1      |
+---------------------------------------------------+----+-------+

+---------------------------------------------------+----+-------+------------------------+---------------+
|Details                                            |Name|Version|Detail                  |TaxDetail      |
+---------------------------------------------------+----+-------+------------------------+---------------+
|[[123, [[val1, val2,,]]], [234, [[,, val3, val4]]]]|json|1      |[123, [[val1, val2,,]]] |[val1, val2,,] |
|[[123, [[val1, val2,,]]], [234, [[,, val3, val4]]]]|json|1      |[234, [[,, val3, val4]]]|[,, val3, val4]|
+---------------------------------------------------+----+-------+------------------------+---------------+

+----+-------+---------------------+
|Name|Version|TaxDetails           |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|json|1      |{"TaxDetail1":"val1"}|
|json|1      |{"TaxDetail2":"val2"}|
|json|1      |{"TaxDetail3":"val3"}|
|json|1      |{"TaxDetail4":"val4"}|
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

Final output as expected by you:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"Name":"json","Version":"1","TaxDetails":"{\"TaxDetail1\":\"val1\"}"}|
|{"Name":"json","Version":"1","TaxDetails":"{\"TaxDetail2\":\"val2\"}"}|
|{"Name":"json","Version":"1","TaxDetails":"{\"TaxDetail3\":\"val3\"}"}|
|{"Name":"json","Version":"1","TaxDetails":"{\"TaxDetail4\":\"val4\"}"}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```